# New column of factors based on shared group values [R]

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have the following data. I'm interested in making a new column of factors that captures whether `Item_i`, `Item_j`, and/or `Item_k` are coded "1" for each category A,B,C,D,etc.

```
dat <- data.frame(c("A","A","B","B","C","C","D","D"), c("x","y","y","z","x","z","y","z"), c(1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0), c(0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0), c(0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1))
names(dat) <- c("Categories","Aspects","Item_i", "Item_j", "Item_k")
```

If I didn't care about the categories and wanted to do this row-by-row, it would be simple enough to do using an `ifelse()` statement:

```
dat$FactorCol <- ifelse(dat$Item_i==1 & dat$Item_j==0 & dat$Item_k==0, "i", NA)
dat$FactorCol <- ifelse(dat$Item_i==0 & dat$Item_j==1 & dat$Item_k==0, "j", dat$FactorCol)
dat$FactorCol <- ifelse(dat$Item_i==0 & dat$Item_j==0 & dat$Item_k==1, "k", dat$FactorCol)
dat$FactorCol <- ifelse(dat$Item_i==1 & dat$Item_j==0 & dat$Item_k==1, "i and k", dat$FactorCol)
```

But what I actually want is for `dat$FactorCol` to reflect whether i, j, k, or some combination appears anywhere within each Category, and then to return a new column (with the same number of rows).

Output would be something like:

```
  Categories Aspects Item_i Item_j Item_k FactorCol
1          A     x      1      0      0         i and j
2          A     y      0      1      0         i and j
3          B     y      0      1      0         i and j and k
4          B     z      1      0      1         i and j and k
5          C     x      1      0      0         i and k
6          C     z      0      0      1         i and k
7          D     y      0      1      0         j and k
8          D     z      0      0      1         j and k
```

It's also not the case in my data that categories restart neatly every two rows. I'm guessing `dplyr()` can handle this easily, but I wasn't able to do it on my own. Appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each `Categories`, we can get `max` value for `'Item_'` columns, for columns which are 1 we assign `i`,`j` or `k` value in each row. To get same number of rows back we `left_join` with `dat`

```
library(dplyr)
cols <- c('i', 'j', 'k')

dat %>%
  group_by(Categories) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with('Item_'), max)) %>%
  #In old dplyr
  #summarise_at(vars(starts_with('Item_')), max)
  mutate(FactorCol = purrr::pmap_chr(select(., starts_with('Item_')), 
                          ~toString(cols[c(...) == 1]))) %>%
  select(Categories, FactorCol) %>%
  left_join(dat, by = 'Categories')


#  Categories FactorCol Items Item_i Item_j Item_k
#  <chr>      <chr>     <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 A          i, j      x          1      0      0
#2 A          i, j      y          0      1      0
#3 B          i, j, k   y          0      1      0
#4 B          i, j, k   z          1      0      1
#5 C          i, k      x          1      0      0
#6 C          i, k      z          0      0      1
#7 D          j, k      y          0      1      0
#8 D          j, k      z          0      0      1
```

Comment: This throws an error for me even with dplyr() and purrr() loaded: Error in across(starts_with("Item_"), max) : could not find function "across"

Comment: `across` is in new `dplyr`. Use `summarise_at(vars(starts_with('Item_')), max)` if you don't have 1.0.0. I have included that as a comment in the original answer.

Comment: This is a cool solution, although it's not totally comprehensible to me and will take some further study to understand why it works. Only one problem: it returns `i,j,k` for any NA categories. How would you get it to return NA intead?

Comment: I think if you add `na.rm = TRUE` in `max` it should fix it? `summarise_at(vars(starts_with('Item_')), max, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't fix it. It's easily fixed with another operation. I was just concerned that something wasn't right under the hood. Looks like it's working okay otherwise though! Thanks for this help